# Changing character values in a data frame column based on a conversion data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R that has a column of strings/characters. I am calling this "myDat" below.

I have another data frame in R that has two columns of strings/characters. I am calling this "conversionDat" below. One column ("Name") contains similar names as the column in "myDat". The other column ("Name2") contains names to which the "myDat" column should be converted to.

Here is a MWE of these two data frames:

```
myDat <- data.frame(Name = c("A","D","P","R"))
conversionDat <- data.frame(Name = c("D","R","A","P"), Name2 = c("S","T","B","Z"))
myDat$Name <- as.character(myDat$Name)
conversionDat$Name <- as.character(conversionDat$Name)
conversionDat$Name2 <- as.character(conversionDat$Name2)
```

I would like to find any case where "myDat" equals a value in "conversionDat$Name" and convert it to "conversionDat$Name2". So, in the MWE above, the "conversionDat" data frame would remain unchanged, but the "myDat" data frame would become:

```
B2
S2
Z2
T2
```

Is there a painless method to go about doing this? Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: An aside: when declaring your `data.frame`s it may be helpful to set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

Comment: You can use `match`: `conversionDat$Name2[match(myDat$Name, conversionDat$Name)]`

Answer (score 1):

A painless method would be to simply merge both and then add the "2" you need in the Name2 column?

```
myDat <- data.frame(Name = c("A","D","P","R"))
conversionDat <- data.frame(Name = c("D","R","A","P"), Name2 = c("S","T","B","Z"))


myDat <- merge(myDat, conversionDat, by = "Name")
myDat$Name2 <- paste(myDat$Name2, "2", sep = "")

> myDat
  Name Name2
1    A    B2
2    D    S2
3    P    Z2
4    R    T2
```